# Glass shader with Substance Painter?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

What is the best option to create glass with Substance Painter and PBR render with Cycles?

I made nice glass in Substance Painter but when I put it in Blender with Principled BSDF and plug opacity roughness (textures from painter) my glass look two times worse because I don't see any dirt and reflection.

This is my shader glass :

[image]

Comment: *"What is the best opption to create glass"* likely there isn't, it depends on requirements of certain project. Your setup isn't going to loos like glass because you want to achieve that with shader without any transmission and only adding transparency. Real glass is a bit more complex. Your end results from both Blender and Substance could help to visualize your *"look 2x worse"*

Comment: Can you send me method or tutorial, where i can make nice glass with susbtance painte texture ?

Comment: I wasn't trying to give tutorials suggestions (which is off-topic here as well), main idea of the comment above was that your material doesn't look like glass at all. First off Principled can behave as glass if you set Transmission value to 1 or alike. Then as glass is dielectric its metalness should be 0. Once Principled behaves like glass set maps from substance to it mixing it with diffuse via roughness etc. factors